# typescript declare var with prototype and new() constructor

Tags: typescript, declare

I am new to Typescript and trying to write a demo to test a kind of strange syntax:

1: define an interface

```
interface FormData {
    append(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
    delete(name: string): void;
    ......
}
```

2: declare an variable, bound with that interface

```
declare var FormData: {
    prototype: FormData;
    new(): FormData;
};
```

3: use the variable as a class somewhere

```
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
```

I regard this declaration as defining an alias for the underlying type `FormData`.

So I try to write a demo to run such kind of syntax:

file1: TestClass.ts

```
export default class Test {
    t: string

    constructor(t: string) {
        this.t = t
    }
}
```

file2: Test.ts

```
import Test from "./TestClass"

declare var Test: {
    prototype: Test;
    new(t: string): Test;
}

const t = new Test("hello");
console.log(t)
```

Run the script with command: `npx ts-node .\test.ts`

I got an erro: TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Test'.

Can anyone help to identify the issue and show the right code to run?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This is not the right use case for `declare var`.